# How to get an error list window in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Visual studio has a window called "Error List" at the bottom left which clearly lists every error in your code. But android studio makes it nearly impossible to even know if there is an error.

Aside from a SERIOUSLY tiny red icon at the top right. I mean this little red circle with an exclamation mark is the size of a grain of rice.

Half the time I don't even know my code has an error because I didn't notice it.

How can I get Android studio to list all code errors in a window? Or if its not in settings can I get an extension that does it?

Comment: Make use of Messages tab at bottom of Android Studio.

Comment: @GokulNathKP There is no Messages tab. It has been removed in the latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "Error List" that lists all the errors line by line (without building the project), since the Editor does that by showing a RED horizontal line in the Margin. Once you build the project however, you will find the list of errors in the "Build" View.

But there is the "Problems" View that will show the list of files that has errors. This will show which files in your project has errors.

[image]